# Makefile unable to install software

Tags: unix, makefile, installation, solaris

So I'm trying to edit a makefile to install software on a Unix system, but I seem to be doing something wrong, since make install keeps failing.

This is the result I get after running `make install`:

```
/usr/sbin/install -m 555 audit /export/home/student/epoll390/bin/audit cp: audit 
and /export/home/student/epoll390/bin/audit are identical *** 
Error code 2 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `install'
```

If anyone could provide some insight into what I am doing wrong, I would be very appreciative. The makefile is below.

```
# Make file for audit

# Location to install binary. Default is /usr/local/bin. You may
# prefer to install it in /usr/bin or /sbin
BINDIR  = /export/home/student/epoll390/bin
#BINDIR=/usr/bin
#BINDIR=/usr/sbin

# Location to install man page. Default is /usr/local/man. You may
# prefer to install it in /usr/man
MANDIR  = /export/home/student/epoll390/bin
#MANDIR = /usr/man

# Compiler to use
CC  = gcc

# Linker to use
LD  = gcc

# Preprocessor options
CPPFLAGS = -DGETOPTLONG

# Compile and link options
# On a.out systems you might want to add -N when linking
# RPM_OPT_FLAGS can be set by rpm tool
# ...For production code
CFLAGS  = -Wall -O3 $(RPM_OPT_FLAGS)
LDFLAGS = -s
# ...For debug
#CFLAGS = -Wall -g
#LDFLAGS = -g

audit:  audit.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o audit audit.o

audit.o: audit.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c audit.c

install: audit
    /usr/sbin/install -m 555 audit $(BINDIR)/audit
    /usr/sbin/install -m 444 audit.1 $(MANDIR)/man1/audit.1

clean:
    $(RM) audit audit.o core *~ results

# check in
ci: clean
    -ci -l *

dist:   clean
    cd .. ; tar --exclude RCS -czvf audit-0.2.tar.gz audit-0.2
```

Comment: You say _specifically, ..._ but the description you provide is anything but specific.  Please show the actual command you entered and the exact error message you got (cut and paste).  These sorts of paraphrased problem descriptions do nothing to help us help you.

Comment: Sorry I was not more descriptive. This is the result I get after running make install:
/usr/sbin/install -m 555 audit /export/home/student/epoll390/bin/audit
cp: audit and /export/home/student/epoll390/bin/audit are identical
*** Error code 2
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `install'

Comment: Also, I'm trying to do this without the use of configure, in order to understand what is actually going on in the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests to me that you are running `make install` in the directory `/export/home/student/epoll390/bin` which happens to be what you set up as `BINDIR`. Thus, the `cp` (subtly disguised by the `install` program) refuses to execute what it (usually correctly) considers an error, i.e., copying a file onto itself.

To fix, run `make clean` in that directory, create `/home/student/epoll390/audit`, move all source files and the makefile into the new directory, `cd` into it, and try again.